# CMake undefined reference to main

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake, linker-errors

When I try to compile my program with `make`, I am getting an undefined reference to main error. Yet, main exists within my src directory, and I feel lost as to what I'm doing wrong.

I assume that `add_executable([title] [source])` is the command used to add source files to the compilation.

**Based on the cmake tutorial**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(opengl_02)
add_executable(opengl_02 opengl_02.cpp)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
add_executable(geometrics geometrics.cpp)
set (opengl_02_version_major 1)
set (openfl_02_version_minor 0)

#configure the header file to pass some of the CMake settings 
#to the source code

configure_file(
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/opengl_02_config.h.in"
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/opengl_02_config.h"
    )

#add the binary tree to the search path for include files
#so that it will find tutorialconfig.h

include_directories("{PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

add_executable(opengl_02_config opengl_02_config.cpp)
```

**Question**

Why is my main file not getting referenced?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (or its equivalent without parameters) must be present in every program. It is hard to say what is wrong with your setup without looking at source code, but I have a feeling that main function is not present in every file that you are trying to compile into executable, i.e. `opengl_02.cpp`, `geometrics.cpp` or `main.cpp`. If you really want to create three executables, `main` function should be present in all three source files in your example. If you want to create executable from three source files, you have to specify all of them for a single executable, like `add_executable(main main.cpp opengl_02.cpp geometrics.cpp)`. Hope it helps.

Comment: That last bit is what I needed. Thanks, and +1